# Does AWS X-ray or CloudWatch capture the HTTP response header Content-Encoding?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-xray, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have an application hosted in AWS which looks to occassionally give responses which have the following header and value. It is not all the time, which is what I find odd.

Content-Encoding: gzip

What I would like to know is whether I can use either AWS X-ray or CloudWatch to query for any responses that have had the **Content-Encoding** header output.

I have checked the AWS X-Ray filters but I cannot seen anything that allows me to search for headers that was contained in a response.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AWS X-Ray does not provide a mechanism to capture HTTP header values in the responses, so it would probably not work out for you.
I'm not sure of CloudWatch though.

Comment: ok, thanks for the heads up on AWS X-Ray, Prashant.